# Synthesizing iVars from properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can I just check what is happening when you do the following (See below), I am right in thinking that no iVars are created in "INTERFACE" just three properties. In the "IMPLEMENTATION" those three properties are assigned to iVars called `_window`, `_animationTimer` & `_currentFrame` which are created by the `@synthesize` command?

```
// INTERFACE
@interface testDelegate : NSObject ... {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimer *animationTimer;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int currentFrame;
...
```

.

```
// IMPLEMENTATION
@implementation testDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize animationTimer = _animationTimer;
@synthesize currentFrame = _currentFrame;
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that's how it works. `@synthesize` can now automatically generate the appropriate instance variables as well as accessors for them. It's a relatively recent development in the language.

Comment: Adding to that, if you just did `@synthesize propertyName`, it'd create instance variables with the same names as the properties, still no need to declare them anywhere.

Comment: Say, I'd create a `@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL isValid;` without synthesizing but implementing the getter. Would this increase the size of each instance of the class?

Comment: @Jenox: No, it wouldn't. Neither properties (per se) nor methods affect the size of instances.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just to make sure I correctly understood it, one more question: if I'd like to have a property + ivar with custom getters and setters, I would still need to synthesize it in order to create the ivar, correct?

Comment: @Jenox: That, or you could just declare an ivar.